# Android project building failed with `TransformException`

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-studio-3.0

My Android project build success with Android Studio 2.3, but on Android Studio 3.0.0-alpha7, it throws this exception:

```
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForStagingDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForStagingDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/facebook/R$attr.class
```

There is only 1 library that working with Facebook and declare Facebook SDK inside:

```
compile('ly.kite:facebook-photo-picker:1.2.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.facebook.android', module: 'facebook-android-sdk'
    }
```

Is this problem of Android Studio or Library?

*Update: * This is entire dependencies in the project:

```
dependencies {
    provided fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.13'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobileanalytics:2.2.13'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.13'
    compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.1.4'
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.daasuu:animateHorizontalProgressBar:0.2.0'
    compile 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    provided files('libs/isoviewer-1.0-RC-28.jar')
    provided files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.ms-square:expandableTextView:0.1.4'
    compile 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.apptentive:apptentive-android:3.0.0'
    compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
    compile 'com.github.delight-im:Android-SimpleLocation:v1.0.1'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.github.alex-townsend:SwipeOpenItemTouchHelper:1.2.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.pusher:pusher-java-client:0.3.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
//    compile 'com.github.boxme:squarecamera:1.1.0'
    compile "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.2@aar'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.lamydev:android-notification:3.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-camera:0.2.14'
    compile 'at.blogc:expandabletextview:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:cam2:0.6.6'
    compile 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.2.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13'
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-4'
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-4'
    compile('com.papertrailapp:logback-syslog4j:1.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback'
    }
    compile 'com.github.darsh2:MultipleImageSelect:3474549'
    compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.9.8"
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
//    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0+"
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    compile 'net.yazeed44.imagepicker:imagepicker:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.IHNEL:android-media-picker:git_hub-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'me.amiee:nicetab:1.0.0'
    compile 'io.github.rockerhieu:emojicon:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu:library:1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.18.0'
    compile('ly.kite:facebook-photo-picker:1.2.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.facebook.android', module: 'facebook-android-sdk'
    }
    compile 'com.github.IHNEL:android-oauth2-client:-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.github.IHNEL:emojicon:-SNAPSHOT'
 }
```

Comment: It's an alpha version, so I am going to guess it's android studio.  Alpha means the developers have barely even tested it yet.

Comment: It works without any problem on my 2 other projects

Comment: are using the same gradle version ?

Comment: Clean and Rebuild project?

Comment: Same JDK version?

Comment: I checked. This problem caused by old gradle version 2.3.2. But when I upgrade to gradle 3.0.0-alpha7, I got another problem:
`Failed to resolve: com.google.android:android:2`. Anyone have same problem?